# change alert message text color using javascript

Tags: javascript

Am using the below script to change the color of the script but showing 'font color="red">Hello world /font> like this.Is any possible way to change the alert text color..

```
<html>
<head>
<title>JavaScript String fontcolor() Method</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

var str = new String("Hello world");

alert(str.fontcolor( "red" ));

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No it is not possible, but you can use a custom alert box, made up of div

Comment: try modal message from Jquery UI , http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal

Answer (score 11):

No. `alert()` accepts a string and renders it using a native widget. There is no provision to style it.

The closest you could get would be to modify the HTML document via the DOM to display the message instead of using an `alert()`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use JQuery to resolve your Problem

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>JavaScript String fontcolor() Method</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-                  ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<script>
$(function() {
 $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
  modal: true,
  buttons: {
  Ok: function() {
   $( this ).dialog( "close" );
   } 
}});
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
 <div id="dialog-message" title="My Dialog Alternative">
 <p style='color:red'> Hello world </p>
 </div>
</body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Hope this help :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>JavaScript String fontcolor() Method</title>
<style>
#alertoverlay{display: none;
    opacity: .8;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background: #FFF;
    width: 100%;}

#alertbox{display: none;
    position: fixed;
    background: #000;
    border:7px dotted #12f200;
    border-radius:10px; 
    font-size:20px;}

#alertbox > div > #alertboxhead{background:#222; padding:10px;color:#FFF;}
#alertbox > div > #alertboxbody{ background:#111; padding:40px;color:red; } 
#alertbox > div > #alertboxfoot{ background: #111; padding:10px; text-align:right; }
</style><!-- remove padding for normal text alert -->

<script>
function CustomAlert(){
    this.on = function(alert){
        var winW = window.innerWidth;
        var winH = window.innerHeight;

        alertoverlay.style.display = "block";
        alertoverlay.style.height = window.innerHeight+"px";
        alertbox.style.left = (window.innerWidth/3.5)+"pt";
        alertbox.style.right = (window.innerWidth/3.5)+"pt"; // remove this if you don't want to have your alertbox to have a standard size but after you remove modify this line : alertbox.style.left=(window.inner.Width/4);
    alertbox.style.top = (window.innerHeight/10)+"pt";
        alertbox.style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('alertboxhead').innerHTML = "JavaScript String fontcolor() Method :";
        document.getElementById('alertboxbody').innerHTML = alert;
        document.getElementById('alertboxfoot').innerHTML = '<button onclick="Alert.off()">OK</button>';
    }
    this.off = function(){
        document.getElementById('alertbox').style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('alertoverlay').style.display = "none";
    }
}
var Alert = new CustomAlert();
</script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="black">
<div id="alertoverlay"></div>
<div id="alertbox">
  <div>
    <div id="alertboxhead"></div>
    <div id="alertboxbody"></div>
    <div id="alertboxfoot"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<script>Alert.on("Hello World!");</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The concept is taken from this : http://www.developphp.com/video/JavaScript/Custom-Alert-Box-Programming-Tutorial

Comment: **Stop** using paid URL shorteners - those are regarded as spam.