# how to change the color of a pupop alert using typescript in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, alert

i'm working with tysprcript in angular.
now i have created a popup alert in a if condition like:

```
if(text != null){
alert("Success!!")
}else{
alert("Failed!")
}
```

Do know someone how i can modify the color or the style of this message? for example green for success and red for failed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not change the window.alert color. It gets a string as an argument and displays it. The proper way to do this is using something like `snackbar`  or you can write your own `popup` you can do both using Angular Material

angular material snackbar:
https://material.angular.io/components/snack-bar/overview

angular matetial dialogs:
https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview

but if you insist on doing so, you can achieve that using jQuery which has been explained in the following question:

[change alert message text color using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451873/change-alert-message-text-color-using-javascript)

Comment: Okay thanks.. i'll do it with angular material dialog